# Conversion of 11,200 MWh to a XX MW facility

Tags: conversion, battery-storage

How large of a battery storage facility (in MW) would be needed to supply 11,200 MWh of electricity for 4 hours before becoming completely discharged.

The facility would be comprised of lithium ion batteries.

The text below may supply some context:
"The Applicants assume that a smaller-scale, alternative energy battery storage involves the installation of smaller-scale batteries and associated equipment to supplement the gas supply system at times when additional capacity is needed... assume that smaller-scale battery storage would supply four hours of electric supply, including approximately 11,200 MWh of energy storage capacity."

Please don't put on hold. there was some incredibly useful discussion coming from this horribly presented question.

Comment: You are mixed up. Define the maximum load power required (MW) the run time (h) and the product of the two gives you the required capacity (MWh). If the load is 11,200 MW then for a four hour run you need 44,800 MWh capacity. A question edit is required.

Comment: I realize that its on a massive scale. It is a hypothetical at the moment. So, a 2,800 MW facility would have approximately 11,200 MWh of storage capacity?

Comment: Are you competing with Leon Musk for supply to AU?  good homework question.

Comment: @gyoung1986 Well, if it is only momentarily hypothetical, do keep me near the top of the list when it moves towards reality. I've always wanted to own a small, modest-sized continent somewhere. The way to word it is: "In order to be able to comply with a continuous demand for 2800 MW for a period of up to 4 hours, you would also need a facility able to safely and continuously maintain 11200 MWh of battery storage capacity."

Comment: Tesla offered something like this for free is not delivered to AU  working in 10 wks something on the order of $1/kWh

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yeah, but that's some piss-ant 129 MWh. We are talking about 100 of those. Mr. Musk will need to work a lot harder to make me all that storage. I'll own him. ;) ... And a few countries, too.

Comment: I think he was dumping old technology not used in Model S

Comment: @jonk I wish this was homework. This is legit work, I'm not an engineer and this is a little beyond me. :( Does it still have the same meaning if I give you the wording from the analysis I was provided... "The Applicants assume that a smaller-scale, alternative energy battery storage involves the installation of smaller-scale batteries and associated equipment to supplement the gas supply system at times when additional capacity is needed... assume that smaller-scale battery storage would supply four hours of electric supply, including approximately 11,200 MWh of energy storage capacity."

Comment: bid $1/Wh might cover costs and margin.

Comment: or about $10b .

Comment: @gyoung1986 Dividing MWh by h gives you MW. (Seem simple enough?). So 11200 MWh equals 2800MW for 4 hours, or 5600MW for 2 hours, or 1 MW for 11200 hours. I assume that's the theoretical ballpark calculation you're looking for. Now, if you are to actually build a storage plant of 11200 MWh you'll want to be a lot more sure about the details, like efficiency, and maximum discharge rate.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 At $1/Wh, 11200 MWh is $11.2 billion US. And that doesn't include all the infrastructure to deliver all of that energy in just 4 hours, which itself isn't the least bit "cheap." Just imagining the capacity needed to discharge all that storage in just 4 hours?? Wow! Plus generation. Plus maintenance. I'd like a piece of that pie! A *large* nuclear power plant might spec out at 1400 MW. This is two of those!

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 They've $10B for the facility alone is about what PriceWaterhouseCooper calculated.

Comment: @gyoung1986 That applicant statement is a bit vague on details. If this is legit work, you need to enter into a discussion to hash out exact details.

Comment: Does that include getting excess energy from gas at cheaper rates or Solar ?

Comment: The whole project is to comply with CEQA, and supply alternatives to a proposed project which is a massive gas transmission line through he center of San Diego. A "2,800 MW" battery storage facility alternative would supply an equivalent amount of energy as a 36" NG PL if all the gas were used to generate electricity. Excess grid energy would be used to recharge the batteries during non-peak demand. All hypothetical and speculative. They left the statement vague on purpose so the fine details couldn't be hashed out quickly and they wouldn't end up obligated to battery storage over a pipeline.

Comment: I can ask my son-in- law what he knows about cost reduction thru microgrid storage and control systems (his expertise) because the economy of scale in central storage may be like mainframes were to PC’s. expensive elephants....

Comment: @gyoung1986 11200 MWh is about 40 billion BTU. We measure planetary annual energy consumption in quads. One day's planetary use, for all uses and from all sources, is close to one quad. So you must store 0.004% of a day's planetary usage from all sources. About 10 kilotons of TNT, roughly. Don't put all your lithium ion batteries in the same basket!

Comment: I’d build it underground like in Area51 but like factories in Japan, floating on elastomers not near the ocean or San Andreas fault, so solar heat does not affect battery life or A/C consumption.  LA is getting AES to supply 400MWh Lithium pulse power within 5yrs to replace gas peakers due to leak risks.  The pressure in gas pipes is incredible, but not has high as nuclear and 10kAtmospheres

Comment: If this is for convincing the government as to why batteries are impractical, then they're probably more interested in things like cost (versus the pipeline - remember to include the cost of electricity for recharging vs the cost of gas!), environmental impact, and hazards than they are interested in physical size.

Comment: It spirals up pretty fast with energy consumption going to e-cars and standby e-storage to prevent blackouts from leaking gas pipeline shutdowns then there is only limited time to fix a pipe which can be a leak hard to find.

Comment: "some incredibly useful discussion" - That's a clear sign it **should** be closed. The StackExchange sites are designed for Questions&Answers, not discussion. Comments offer some space for discussion, but that's intended to fix a question or answer. Please note that you can still fix a question while it's closed - that is exactly why it's closed and not deleted. But a question about basic math, such as dividing 11200 by 4 is not on-topic; a fix would have to highlight why this question is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually kind of a fun experimental thought, because I actually don't have any experience with anything of this magnitude (or several orders below it, to be honest.) This is way out of my experience. Which is why it's fun. (I must admit though that I've been involved in developing a product used by power companies in the US and in China for monitoring the oil temperatures at many internal points within large power transformers used for energy distribution. For those engineers out there... consider the difficulty of placing wires and/or anything electronic inside of a \$2500\:\textrm{kVA}\$ power transformer.)

---

Your specifications:

- \$11.2\times 10^9\:\textrm{W-hr}\$ of energy storage capacity.
- \$2.8\times 10^9\:\textrm{W}\$ power delivery capacity.
- Able to sustain #2 for \$4\:\textrm{hr}\$,
- Lithium ion battery storage technology (perhaps [Tesla PowerPack](https://www.tesla.com/powerpack))

The above is able to completely replace a 36" natural gas pipeline, where all of the full-up gas capacity of that pipeline is used to generate electricity, for a period of up to four hours.

---

Tesla's PowerPack specifications are:

- Energy Capacity: \$210\times 10^3\:\textrm{W-hr}\$
- Power: \$50\times 10^3\:\textrm{W}\$
- System Efficiency: 89% round-trip (4 hour system)
- Depth of Discharge: 100%
- Dimensions: 51.5" x 32.4" x 86", or about \$2.4\:m^3\$
- Weight: \$1622\:\textrm{kg}\$

Tesla's Inverter specifications are:

- Power: \$50\times 10^3\:\textrm{W}\$
- Dimensions: 39.9" x 49.4" x 86.3", or about \$2.8\:m^3\$
- Weight: \$1200\:\textrm{kg}\$
- (Scalable Inverter Maximum: \$625\times 10^3\:\textrm{VA}\$)

---

From the above, we can make some deductions.

- Tesla's PowerPack modules provide a nifty full-load to full-discharge time of 4.2 hours. Quite convenient. I strongly suspect that Tesla's specifications have informed the situation here.
- Your specifications use watts and fail to take into account the difference between watts and volt-amps. Practical systems delivering this kind of power will need to pay very close attention to these differences and size themselves appropriately. They may also require added components to support power-factor adjustments. These cost money, take space, and require support and maintenance.
- Tesla's standard inverters can't scale to your needs. They fall short by a factor of almost 20000. You'll need to find out what kind of inverters can be scaled up in order to achieve what you need.
- Assuming Tesla's inverters could be scaled up, you'd need 56,000 of them.
- You'd also need 56,000 of their PowerPack storage modules.
- If everything were stacked side-by-side, with no hallways or room for getting in there and repairing or replacing anything or for dissipation of heat, you'd need almost 300,000 cubic meters of volume to store them. If you avoid stacking them, that's 34 acres -- jammed tight. Clearly, you'd need a LOT more than 34 acres.
- None of this deals with the requirements for distribution and support for that distribution from the inverters. Nor does it deal with building space for personnel, their support (food, airconditioning, workspaces, etc.), the storage needed for equipment and parts, shipping docks, roads, etc.

And like I said, you need to isolate these units from each other. You would NOT want the explosive failure of a unit or two to cascade into failures of nearby units.

There are lots of other details. I assumed 100% efficiency above. Tesla claims 89%. Assuming Tesla takes into account all of the final system's losses (which I'm sure their figures don't), you'd need 63000 pairs of modules and not 56000. (I'd say you should tentatively plan on 75000, until you can refine the figure down more precisely.) You also need to work out how to shift loads onto and off of the grid and how to deal with replacing failed distribution components while they are operating. Things fail under heavy load and when they fail, if you must maintain continuous operation, you need to be able to move that load onto another unit (without risking its destruction, too) and isolate the unit you need to replace and bring back on line. In the meantime, the temporarily "overloaded" unit may heat up beyond its specifications. Or if it doesn't, it will certainly age faster than before. So you need to keep track of the rate of aging of all of these components so you can anticipate and avoid, rather than respond to disasters.

And I really have to wonder about a system that only gets used once in a while. If it only gets used during extreme cases of need, odds are that is also exactly when you will find out there are problems. So I'm pretty sure the system needs regular testing and use to maintain it's ability to function in a pinch.

I can only begin to see some of the fun, here. I hope you have a good team on hand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking right now at an 18650 battery, and it says on the side it has a capacity of 8.14Wh.

So assuming your question is actually about supplying 11,200MWh of electricity over a period of 4 hours, you would need 11,200,000,000/8.14=1,375,921,376 batteries.

Four batteries fit into a holder measuring 80mm x 75mm x 20mm, giving a volume of 0.00012m<sup>3</sup>, so the total volume of your facility in terms of batteries alone would be 1,375,921,376/4*0.00012=41,277m<sup>3</sup>.

The question now is how much extra space you need for the charging and protection circuitry, physical housing and support, cabling, heating, cooling, ventilation and physical access gangways. Let's go for a factor of 5, which might work if we don't make the building too high; that gives a total volume of 206,385m<sup>3</sup>.

If we make the building 10m high that means a floor area of just under 144m square. Clearly a lot of guesswork involved but it gives you an idea. It's big but it seems possible assuming there's enough lithium available in the world for the batteries and you can wait long enough for them to be manufactured.

Answer (score 0):

AES is building the largest today in SD area.

- 120 MWh/30 MW –  for San Diego Gas & Electric in Escondido, California.

The AES Energy Storage systems utilizes 400,000 lithium-ion cells supplied by Samsung SDI in 20,000 modules and 24 containers.

Scale up vertically requires safety inspection of battery containers and weight management, not to mention it would be safer under-ground from environmental threats on earthquake proof platforms.

In 2012 in Ontario, Canada, costs for nuclear generation stood at 5.9¢/kWh while hydroelectricity, at 4.3¢/kWh, cost 1.6¢ less than nuclear. By September 2015, the cost of solar in the US dropped below nuclear generation costs, averaging 5¢/kWh.

India has Solar slightly cheaper than coal at 4¢/kWh but no storage.

Nuclear power in Ontario with several GW stations is still profitable according to my Nuclear Eng friend in the biz at Pickering, inspite of being only 50% efficient and heating up Lake Ontario with a 10’C rise on cooling water return to the Lake.